# Is there a bedrock equivalent to Java double carpets?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

In Minecraft Java Edition, doubled carpets block villager pathfinding, including searching for job blocks.

In Bedrock, where pathfinding is notoriously bad and villagers can connect to job blocks that they can't physically reach, is there a way to block their pathfinding like this?

Answer (score -1):

In bedrock mobs use pathfinding by sight so if you put any non-transparent block in between the villager and the job block it will stop the pathfinding, also slabs can work to stop pathfinding.

Comment: Citations, examples please? I'll test this later but it hasn't worked in the past.